# How to remove '\x' from a hex string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, wave

I'm reading a `wav` audio file in Python using `wave` module. The `readframe()` function in this library returns frames as hex string. I want to remove `\x` of this string, but `translate()` function doesn't work as I want:

```
>>> input = wave.open(r"G:\Workspace\wav\1.wav",'r')
>>> input.readframes (1)
'\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
>>> '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'.translate(None,'\\x')
'\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
>>> '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'.translate(None,'\x')
ValueError: invalid \x escape
>>> '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'.translate(None,r'\x')
'\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
>>>
```

Any way I want divide the result values by 2 and then add `\x` again and generate a new `wav` file containing these new values. Does any one have any better idea?

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, you don't have backslashes in your string. So, that's why you can't remove them.

If you try to play with each hex character from this string (using `ord()` and `len()` functions - you'll see their real values. Besides, the length of your string is just 4, not 16.

You can play with several solutions to achieve your result:
'hex' encode:

```
'\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'.encode('hex')
'ff1f00e8'
```

Or use `repr()` function:

```
repr('\xff\x1f\x00\xe8').translate(None,r'\\x')
```

Comment: Does it have any reverse way to? I mean how can I convert 'ff1f00e8' to '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8' again? any Decode function?

Comment: Reverse: `'ff1f00e8'.decode('hex')` :) What about length - was playing with backslashes in the initial string.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do what you want is:

```
>>> s = '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
>>> ''.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in s)
'ff1f00e8'
```

---

The reason why `translate` is not working is that what you are seeing is not the string itself, but its representation. In other words, `\x` is not contained in the string:

```
>>> '\\x' in '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
False
```

`\xff`, `\x1f`, `\x00` and `\xe8` are the hexadecimal representation of for characters (in fact, `len(s) == 4`, not `24`).

Answer (score 3):

Use the encode method:

```
>>> s = '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'
>>> print s.encode("hex")
'ff1f00e8'
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a hexadecimal representation, **encode** with **hex**

```
>>> '\xff\x1f\x00\xe8'.encode('hex')
'ff1f00e8'
```