# python utf-8 coding handling '\'

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to print a string in utf-8 form,the ideal result is as follow :

[image]

[image]

and it actually works that way if I mean it.

However,when i try to print another string just seems like it,the result is

[image]

and i have found out what is wrong,but i don't know how to fix it.
The problem is the string i am trying to print is:

[image]

i try to remove one of the '\',but it means one '\' when there is actually '\\',yet the difference is made.
can someone save me from this puzzle? Thanks a lot!

Comment: copy and paste your 'code' within the question; it makes it easier for people to help you out.

Comment: right,but this is just an example.I have a text full of this,and i want to print them right

Comment: So you expect us to type out your example?

Comment: if u have a solution,i am listening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove '\x' from a hex string in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707954/how-to-remove-x-from-a-hex-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `"\\xe6\\x90\\x9c".decode('string_escape')`

[image: example]

Comment: OMG,that is a bingo! Thanks!